# How to filter a Model which having nested array in swift

Tags: swift, filter, append

I am having model

```
class Consumer360PurchaseHistoryDetails: Codable {
    var freqofPurchase : String?
    var freqofVisit : String?
    var customerPurchaseHistory : [CustomerPurchaseHistory]?
    init() {
    }
}

class CustomerPurchaseHistory : Codable {
    var dateOfPurchase : String?
    var products : [PurchaseProducts]?
    init() {
    }
}

class PurchaseProducts : Codable {
    var productID : String?
    var productFilterType : String?
    init() {
    }
}
```

I want to filter this model by productFilterType in PurchaseProducts

I tried the below way

```
    var dataModel: Consumer360PurchaseHistoryDetails?

    var tempDataModel:Consumer360PurchaseHistoryDetails = Consumer360PurchaseHistoryDetails()

  for purchaseHistory in self.dataModel?.customerPurchaseHistory ?? [] {
            for product in purchaseHistory.products ?? [] {
                if product.productFilterType?.lowercased() == StringConstants.purchase {
                    tempDataModel.freqofVisit = "three"
                    tempDataModel.freqofPurchase = "five"
                    tempDataModel.customerPurchaseHistory?.append(purchaseHistory)
                }
            }
        }
        self.purchaseHistoryTableView.dataModel = self.tempDataModel
```

But the purchaseHistory is not getting appended in customerPurchaseHistory, which is is always nil after appending. But the freqofVisit and freqofPurchase is getting updated. Am i want use index for appending?

Comment: You need to be quite clear here. What elements do you want to keep exactly? Do you want to keep the whole purchase history as long as it has one purchase product that satisfy the condition, or remove the purchase products that don't satisfy the condition from the purchase histories as well?

Comment: init customerPurchaseHistory in your tempDataModel by default it is nil

Comment: @Sweeper I just want to have the purchase history which satisfy the condition in tempDataModel, I don't want the change the dataModel's data. In someother words i want to filter the dataModel which satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tempDataModel.customerPurchaseHistory? is set to nil by default. So the below code won't be executed.

```
tempDataModel.customerPurchaseHistory?.append(purchaseHistory)
```

Just above your for loop, assign its value to empty array, like this:

```
tempDataModel.customerPurchaseHistory = []
```

So, your code looks like this:

```
var dataModel: Consumer360PurchaseHistoryDetails?

var tempDataModel:Consumer360PurchaseHistoryDetails = Consumer360PurchaseHistoryDetails()
tempDataModel.customerPurchaseHistory = []
for purchaseHistory in self.dataModel?.customerPurchaseHistory ?? [] {
        for product in purchaseHistory.products ?? [] {
            if product.productFilterType?.lowercased() == StringConstants.purchase {
                tempDataModel.freqofVisit = "three"
                tempDataModel.freqofPurchase = "five"
                tempDataModel.customerPurchaseHistory?.append(purchaseHistory)
            }
        }
    }
    self.purchaseHistoryTableView.dataModel = self.tempDataModel
```

Comment: glad to help :)